# How to get a sum of all rows that meets condition in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to return sums with their specific conditions.

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*),
  SUM("transactionTotal" WHERE "entryType"=sold) as soldtotal,
  SUM(case when "entryType"=new then "transactionTotal" else 0 end) as newtotal
FROM "MoneyTransactions"
WHERE cast("createdAt" as date) BETWEEN '2020-10-08' AND '2020-10-09'
```

I am trying to sum up the rows with `"entryType"=sold` and `"entryType"=new` and return those values separately.
obviously both my logic are wrong.
can someone lend a hand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were on the right track to use conditional aggregation, but your syntax is slightly off.  Try this version:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS total_cnt,
    SUM(transactionTotal) FILTER (WHERE entryType = 'sold') AS soldtotal,
    SUM(transactionTotal) FILTER (WHERE entryType = 'new')  AS newtotal
FROM MoneyTransactions
WHERE
    createdAt::date BETWEEN '2020-10-08' AND '2020-10-09';
```

Note: Assuming your `createdAt` column already be date, then there is no point in casting it.  If it is *text*, then yes you would need to convert it, but you might have to use `TO_DATE` depending on its format.